# How to generate unique id for the web browser?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, refresh-token

I want to implement unique id for the web browser using **C#**. It must be consider all the browser and the incognito windows too?
How to generate?

**My scenario**
I am using the angularjs with web api token. I have included the refresh token too.

After user logged in from one browser, then if user logged in to the another browser, I am providing new refresh token for the same user. So when user access another page, he gets log out.

So I want to identify the user based on the unique browser.
Is this ok?

Or can I generate the guid when the user log in.

Comment: GUID is a good Idea

Comment: Why not use a cookie to store the id. Set a unique id when they first log in, then it doesn't matter what browser they are using or if it is incognito mode as it will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is ok. Since, you need to register or identify clients if you want different refresh tokens for different clients or browsers. GUID could be used.

Whether you should identify browsers or register new clients, depends on your application/websites scope and security considerations.